# $x=2^{x^{x^{.^{.^{.}}}}}$ solve for $x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

$x=2^{x^{x^{.^{.^{.}}}}}$
My attempt at solving the question:
$$\log_2x=x^{x^{x^{.^{.^{.}}}}}$$
Now here I use a trivial trick which I have seen in my class to substitute infinite powers.
$$\log_2x=x^{\log_2x}$$
After that I have no idea how to solve this equation.

I opened the graph and solution of the question [on Wolfram|Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=logx(log2(x))%3Dlog2(x)) but I could not understand what is written.

Comment: Your transformation with logarithms is wrong.

Comment: The expression $$((((2^x)^x)^x)^x\dots)$$ equivalent to $$2^{(x\cdot x\cdot x\cdot x\cdot x\dots)}$$  is meaningless – unless you define it as a limit of $$2^{(x^n)}$$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: You corrected the first line but not the title.  They now do not agree.

Answer (score 1):

The equation you wrote is equivalent to $$x=2^{x^\infty}, $$ which has no solution. (If $x<1$, it reduces to $x=2^0=1$, if $x=1$ to $x=2^1=2$ and $x>1$ to $x=2^\infty=\infty$.)

Comment: I`m sorry for the inconvenience but I have corrected the question now.

Answer (score 0):

Your right side only makes sense as a limit of a tower, the limit of 
$$2, 2^x, 2^{x^x}, 2^{x^{x^x}} \ldots$$  If there is such a limit $L$, we must have $L^x=L$, which can be satisfied for $L=0,1$ or for $x=1$.  You should be able to convince yourself that all the terms of the series are greater than $1$, but if $x \lt 1$ the series will converge to $1$.  Unfortunately, if $x=1$ the series is a constant $2$.  In neither case does the tower converge to $x$, so the equation has no real solution.

Comment: With the given parenthesing, a power tower is excluded.

Comment: That's wrong, because $(2^x)^x \ne 2^{x^x}$ in general (the exception is $x=2$).

Comment: @YvesDaoust:  My series was wrong and I have fixed it.  It turns out the rest of the argument goes through.

Comment: Yep, but it still isn't a tower.

Comment: I`m sorry for the inconvenience but I have corrected the question now.

Comment: My original answer was to the question that is now in the body.  There still is no solution.  I have rolled back.